# Why is mintinline inside `text` inserting a stray n character at the end of the code?

Tags: minted

The following:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setminted{breaklines,breakafter={_}}

\begin{document}

$\text{\mintinline{python}{i_have_a_lot_of_underscores_and_it_makes_me_very_very_very_long}}$

\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

Where is this final `n` coming from, and how can I remove it?

This weirdly happens for `python` and `lua` but not `text`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Not saying it's perfect, but from the doc: "The \mintinline command will already work in many
places that do not allow normal verbatim commands like \verb, so make sure to try it first." Also, "Unlike \verb, \mintinline can usually be used inside other commands."

Comment: The extra n does not appear if `\text` is replaced with `\mbox`